# Replace array in object with object in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have a huge JSON that I need to load. I'm trying to reduce the size of it by using arrays within the objects, but I don't find a proper way to back-translate it in Typescript.

Instead of repeating the dates in every object of this array, I thought I use a column called "values" and use typescript to assign the dates again.

This is what I'm retrieving:

```
  const rows = [
    {
      'name': '100100',
      'description': 'Dummy 00',
      'hierarchy': ['Final_Hierarchy'],
      'id': 0,
      'values': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    '2022-09-18',
    '2022-09-25',
    '2022-10-02',
    '2022-10-09',
    '2022-10-16',
    '2022-10-23',
    '2022-10-30',
    '2022-11-06',
    '2022-11-13',
    '2022-11-20',
    '2022-11-27',
    '2022-12-04',
  ];
```

And this is what I need:

```
  const rows = [
    {
      'name': '100100',
      'description': 'Dummy 00',
      'hierarchy': ['Final_Hierarchy'],
      'id': 0,
      '2022-09-18': 0,
      '2022-09-25': 0,
      '2022-10-02': 0,
      '2022-10-09': 0,
      '2022-10-16': 0,
      '2022-10-23': 0,
      '2022-10-30': 0,
      '2022-11-06': 0,
      '2022-11-13': 0,
      '2022-11-20': 0,
      '2022-11-27': 0,
      '2022-12-04': 0,
    },
  ];
```

I tried this, but it returns "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'".

```
var result = {};
  columns.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = rows.values[i]);
```

Does anyone have a solutions for this?

Comment: The short answer is: don't do that. It's a lot easier if you compose things that are themselves type-safe rather than merge things in a way that won't ever be type-safe. Store the date records in an object of type `Record<string, number>` and make that a property on the `rows` object instead. Or even have an object with a metadata property and a records property that have the relevant different parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the good idea you just forgot that rows is an array and that you want to change the first item so try:

```
columns.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = rows[0].values[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll get the following error in that case:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

Comment: Also, how would I iterate over all rows and not just [0]?

Comment: In the case that you would want to do this I would do, `rows.map(row => { const object = { ...row }; columns.forEach((key, i) => object[key] = row.values[i]; return object });`

Comment: For the problem of the error implicit any I would cast the value that it is complaining about to `any`

Answer (score 0):

the first issue is you're trying to access an value of the rows object within the array without first specifying which index of the array you want to access. The next is that typescript is trying to tell you that the key on the object you're trying to assign doesn't exist.

```
const rows = [
    {
        'name': '100100',
        'description': 'Dummy 00',
        'hierarchy': ['Final_Hierarchy'],
        'id': 0,
        'values': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    }
];

const columns = [
    '2022-09-18',
    '2022-09-25',
    '2022-10-02',
    '2022-10-09',
    '2022-10-16',
    '2022-10-23',
    '2022-10-30',
    '2022-11-06',
    '2022-11-13',
    '2022-11-20',
    '2022-11-27',
    '2022-12-04',
];

interface Result {
    [key: string]: number | string | string[];
}

let result: Result = {};

result['name'] = rows[0]['name'];
result['description'] = rows[0]['description'];
result['hierarchy'] = rows[0]['hierarchy'];
result['id'] = rows[0]['id'];

columns.forEach((key, i) => {
    result[key] = rows[0]['values'][i];
})

console.log(result);
```